# (php) How do make my submit button work in ie

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer

My form works in firefox but not ie. I've tried using a hidden text field (fail)... I tried using an image instead of a submit button (fail)... are there any other solutions? Here is my form:

```
<?php

print "<table width='522' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' border='0'>
<tr><td valign='top' width='128'><img src='logo.gif' border='0'></td><td valign='bottom'><div style='padding-top: 10; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;'
<form action='' method='GET'>
Search category
<select name='cat'><option value='1'"; if($cat==1){print "selected='yes'";}print">1</option>
<option value='2'"; if($cat==2){print "selected='yes'";}print">2</option>
<option value='3'"; if($cat==3){print "selected='yes'";}print">3</option>
<option value='4'"; if($cat==4){print "selected='yes'";}print">4</option>
</select>
 for <input type='text' value='$q' name='q'>
<input type='submit' value='Go' />
</form></div></td></tr>
<tr>
</table>";

print "<BR>results here";
?>
```

Comment: Could you give more detail as to what's going on? Some example of your code (both the form and what's trying to use it) and exactly how it's failing?

Comment: Can you specify the "don't work" part? What is the behavior? I don't see anything that could be making it not to work.

Comment: I think I'm fairly familiar with the problem you're referring to, or at least I would be if we saw some code :-), please post the PHP you're using to execute the code based on the submit event.

Comment: print "<form action='' method='GET'>
Search category
<select name='cat'><option value='1'"; if($cat==1){print "selected='yes'";}print">1</option>
<option value='2'"; if($cat==2){print "selected='yes'";}print">2</option>
<option value='3'"; if($cat==3){print "selected='yes'";}print">3</option>
<option value='4'"; if($cat==4){print "selected='yes'";}print">4</option>
</select>
 for <input type='text' value='$q' name='q'>
<input type='submit' value='Go' />
</form>

Comment: note: when submit is pressed NOTHING happens

Comment: No wonder why you can't debug that, what a great example of why you shouldn't echo HTML.

Comment: Another suggestion: I'd code as much HTML outside the php tags as possible. In this example, I'd code at least the table, form and text outside the php code blocks, and then print just the select. Or do most of the content as html and only use php snippets. It just seems clearer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your div is not closed for a start.

```
<div style='padding-top: 10; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;'
```

I've rewritten your code, use this instead ,much more efficient and easier to read / debug:

```
<table width='522' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' border='0'>
    <tr>
        <td valign='top' width='128'><img src='logo.gif' border='0'></td>
        <td valign='bottom'>
            <div style='padding-top: 10; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;' >
                <form action='' method='GET'>
                    Search category
                    <select name='cat'>
                        <option value='1' <?php if($cat==1){echo "selected='yes'";} ?> >1</option>
                        <option value='2' <?php if($cat==2){echo "selected='yes'";} ?> >2</option>
                        <option value='3' <?php if($cat==3){echo "selected='yes'";} ?> >3</option>
                        <option value='4' <?php if($cat==4){echo "selected='yes'";} ?> >4</option>
                    </select>
                    for <input type='text' value='$q' name='q'>
                    <input type='submit' value='Go' />
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<BR>results here
```

Comment: thanks. I closed the div and all is well. however i may clean it up as suggested.

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes it would be recommended you read up on good code readability, we've all been where you are, believe me it gets so much easier to read / debug when it's written cleanly. Also, observe how your check-box selected PHP tags are now embedded in your HTML, this is the best way to do this as the PHP engine doesn't have to output all that HTML, just the `selected='yes'`. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), the outputted HTML has errors in it. I expect Internet Explorer's error recovery process doesn't deal with the code about `<form` being broken (since you are trying to start the form element inside the start tag for another element).